# How to present a type of an element in xml-schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm making a xml schema and I have to present database columns which have name, type and table they belong to. Like this:

```
  <xs:complexType name="tMappingItem">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="table" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? I can naturally do this:

```
     <xs:element name="type" >
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="FLOAT" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DOUBLE" />
            <xs:enumeration value="INT" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DATETIME" />
            <xs:enumeration value="STRING" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
```

if there is no way to tell that "type" is of type type. ;)

Comment: can someone please tell me how to edit my question. i have xml now in pre blocks and it's not working

Comment: am i the 1st person ever that asks xml-question? the reference has nothing about xml...

Comment: @matti I fixed that for you.  Just remove the pre and indent four (4) spaces. Also you can highlight the xml and click the Code **[101]** button.

Comment: How else would XML schema know which strings are types? How would it know which types you accept?

Comment: @john: didn't understand what u mean. what i want is not a string but a metatype. so i want to state that "type"-element's type is all xml types or even better subset of all xml types.

Comment: @matti: sorry, I forgot that you might really have been looking for a concrete representation of the abstract concept of type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that would be nice :) Unfortunately, there is no meta type in XML schema whose value are all the type names. You will have to enumerate them as you do up there.

Comment: yes meta type is exactly what i want. thanks 4 info! i have 2 accept your answer in a bit if nobody else can provide better solution than my "enum" strings...